# Where to put helper methods needed in multiple models in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

As an example:

```
module ModelHelper
  def self.special_function(some_parameter)
    do_some_special_thing
  end
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_special
    ModelHelper.special_function(a_variable_of_here)
  end
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_special
    ModelHelper.special_function(another_variable_of_here)
  end
end
```

Where do I put `model_helper.rb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally make a file in lib and include it.  Something like lib/special_model.rb:

```
module SpecialModel
   included do
     def to_special
       do_some_special_thing
     end
   end
end
```

Then in app/models/student.rb:

```
class Student
  include SpecialModel
end
```

You may also want to look at ActiveSupport::Concern for some rails help when working with modules:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html